# One Drive / Office365 similar scripting language as the Google Apps Script

Tags: api, office365, onedrive

I searched for the One Drive scripting language, but found only this (Live SDK API): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh826521.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

This shares similarities more like a Google Drive API. Does Microsoft OneDrive have web based scripting possibility similar to Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About how to call the Live SDK APIs: the JavaScript API (Windows Store apps and web), the Managed API (Windows Runtime apps), the iOS API, and the Android API . You may want the JavaScript API , please click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243643.aspx) for how to use the Live SDK JavaScript API in your web app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nan, it seems the link you provided is the closest that Microsoft has compared to the Google Apps Script.